# A URL source to trigger a JQUERY overlay event on Load with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I am trying to specify a URL source to trigger a QUERY overlay event on Load with a delay of 2 seconds.

I can get the overlay to work, but it needs to be different for different traffic coming to the site. So I am in need of suggestions to identify 'source URL' to adjust the different. Oh also the overlay should only show once per unique visit to the site?

Here is the overlay code I am using:

```
<script>
      function openColorBox(){
        $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"65%", height:"85%", 
                                    href: "http://www.google.com"});
      }
      setTimeout(openColorBox, 2000);
</script>
```

Comment: I guess I am confused about how this would be different for different sources or viewers. Could you expand on that with some examples. What are you anticipating the experience to be like?